# Estimators and Bias

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Having searched the internet for a while and read a few textbooks that I have found in library, I am unable to answer the very simple question of -

As the number of samples taken from a normal distribution increases should the mean of the estimator be the constant if an unbiased estimator is used, and the mean of the estimator not constant if a biased estimator is used?

I can provide further detail if needed, but I feel like the context of the question is irrelevant, however I have added some below.

The distribution had variance 64, and when I used the estimator $S^2$ for n = 3,10, and 100, the sample means of $S^2$ were 63.9, 64.1 and 63.8, respectively. However, when I used $\bar S^2$ for the same n values, the sample means were 42.5, 58.0, and 63.2. What does this tell me about the estimators?

N.B When I work out sample variances for the estimators, as n increases, both of the sample variances decrease and seem to converge to 64 as well. But I only have 3 samples of 3,10, and 100 so I cant be certain.

Comment: Your question is not well formulated. First of all "n increases in a normal distribution" is not a meaningful sentence. Maybe you are trying to say that you have n samples drawn from a normal distribution. Secondly you have to tell what S and $\bar{S}$ are.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to say, I will edit now. And $S$ and $\bar S$ are standard estimators I believe. $S^2$ is the Sample Variance as an unbiased estimator and $\bar S^2$ is the biased sample variance without a correction.

Comment: An estimator is a random variable, like the random variable which it is trying to estimate a paramater of (i.e. mean, variance). It has a distribution, called the sampling distribution. Since it has a distribution it has a mean itself. But this is a population parameter, hence it is available in the limit. Unbiased estimators have constant mean irrespective of the number of samples, which is equal to the parameter it is estimating. Biased estimator may or may not have a constant mean. If they have a constant mean,then it is bad because increasing number of samples will not converge to anything